# PHP получаю Call to a member function fetch_all() on boolean при запросе через js fetch

Tags: javascript, php

Пожалуйста, помогите! Ничего не понимаю... Вроде, должно все работать.

Спрашиваю с помощью js у сервера:

```
request({url, data}) {
        return fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            },
            redirect: 'follow',
            referrer: 'no-referrer',
            body: data,
        })
        .then(response => response.text());
    }
```

На стороне сервера меня ждут вот с таким:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__.'/../classes/Connection.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/../classes/JSONRewriter.php');
require_once(__DIR__.'/../classes/Purify.php');

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $referrer = POST ...;
    $real_row = ...;

    $newConnection = new Connection();
    $overwriting = Purify::openArray($newConnection->getFromDB(sql-хрень));
    if () {
        ...Обработка результата...
    }

    $newConnection->query(Запись результата);
}
```

Класс для подключения

```
class Connection {
    private $host = ...;
    private $user = ...;
    private $pswd = ...;
    private $dbse = ...;
    public function con() {
        $connect = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pswd, $this->dbse);
        if ($connect->connect_error) throw new Exception('MySQL connection attempt dropped. {$connect->connect_errno}. {$connect->connect_error}');
        return $connect;
    }
    public function query($query) {
        $connect = $this->con();
        mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }
    public function getFromDB($query) {
        $connect = $this->con();
        $response = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        return $response->fetch_all($resulttype = MYSQLI_NUM);
        mysqli_close($connect);
    }
}
```

php работал, пока я спрашивал его через xhr, но на fetch выдает

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_all() on boolean in C:\Users\S_iva\OneDrive\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\localhost\api\classes\Connection.php:22
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\S_iva\OneDrive\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\localhost\api\set\referrer.php(14): Connection-&gt;getFromDB('SELECT content ...')
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>C:\Users\S_iva\OneDrive\Desktop\OSPanel\domains\localhost\api\classes\Connection.php</b> on line <b>22</b><br />
```

Comment: Прошу не судить код строго :) Код в работе совсем недавно

Comment: Знаете когда `mysqli_query` возвращает boolean?

Comment: Но он возвращает mysqli_result Object, я проверил

Answer (score -1, accepted):

У функций есть определенные поведения, которые надо знать или подсматривать в документации. К тому же ошибка явно указывает на функцию, в которой произошла ошибка.

[Функция mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php)

> Возвращает FALSE в случае неудачи. В случае успешного выполнения
>   запросов SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE или EXPLAIN mysqli_query() вернет
>   объект mysqli_result. Для остальных успешных запросов mysqli_query()
>   вернет TRUE.

Ну и выполнить на булевском `false` вызов функции `fetch_all()` закончится неудачей. В общем обрабатывайте возможные ошибки. И да, у вас `mysqli_close($connect);` никогда не отработает т.к. выше `return` из функции.

Comment: Задебажил mysqli_query через print_r, он вернул mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 1
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 1
    [type] => 0
)

Comment: @RyanWright ну так тестируйте полный стек приложения с вызовом из браузера через xhr: `if(!$response) die(mysqli_error($connect));` и уже только потом `return $response->fetch_all($resulttype = MYSQLI_NUM);`

Comment: @RyanWright а еще лучше сохранили результат в переменную `$result = $response->fetch_all($resulttype = MYSQLI_NUM);`, потом закрыли соединение `mysqli_close($connect);` и уже затем вернули результат `return $result;`;

Comment: Оказалось, у пользователя не было прав на SELECT 
Какой же я тупой)

Comment: Не подскажите, чем отличаются вызов fetch_all из переменной response после закрытия и сохранение вывода fetch? Работает и так, и так

Comment: @RyanWright в данном случае ничем не должно отличаться. А так можно возвращать данные из БД не сразу большим массивом, а порциями по мере необходимости через какую-нибудь `mysqli_store_result`. Тогда закрытие соединения приведет к ошибке. У меня же это по привычке, всегда ставить в конец, на всякий случай и отпадает необходимость забивать голову допущениями.